# cucumber --tag=@homepage_page --format progress --format html --out=reports/feature.html cannot load such file -- rspec (LoadError)

Tags: ruby, rspec, cucumber

```
cucumber --tag=@homepage_page --format progress --format html --out=reports/feature.html cannot load such file -- rspec (LoadError)
```

When I try to generate the HTML reports, I am getting this error:

```
cannot load such file -- rspec (LoadError)
/Library/Ruby/Site/2.0.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:55:in `require'
/Library/Ruby/Site/2.0.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:55:in `require'
/Users/eun081/Documents/Ajay/PROJECTS/COMPLETED/Updated/Automation/features/support/env.rb:1:in `<top (required)>'
/Library/Ruby/Gems/2.0.0/gems/cucumber-2.4.0/lib/cucumber/rb_support/rb_language.rb:96:in `load'
/Library/Ruby/Gems/2.0.0/gems/cucumber-2.4.0/lib/cucumber/rb_support/rb_language.rb:96:in `load_code_file'
/Library/Ruby/Gems/2.0.0/gems/cucumber-2.4.0/lib/cucumber/runtime/support_code.rb:142:in `load_file'
/Library/Ruby/Gems/2.0.0/gems/cucumber-2.4.0/lib/cucumber/runtime/support_code.rb:84:in `block in load_files!'
/Library/Ruby/Gems/2.0.0/gems/cucumber-2.4.0/lib/cucumber/runtime/support_code.rb:83:in `each'
/Library/Ruby/Gems/2.0.0/gems/cucumber-2.4.0/lib/cucumber/runtime/support_code.rb:83:in `load_files!'
/Library/Ruby/Gems/2.0.0/gems/cucumber-2.4.0/lib/cucumber/runtime.rb:253:in `load_step_definitions'
/Library/Ruby/Gems/2.0.0/gems/cucumber-2.4.0/lib/cucumber/runtime.rb:61:in `run!'
/Library/Ruby/Gems/2.0.0/gems/cucumber-2.4.0/lib/cucumber/cli/main.rb:32:in `execute!'
/Library/Ruby/Gems/2.0.0/gems/cucumber-2.4.0/bin/cucumber:8:in `<top (required)>'
/usr/local/bin/cucumber:22:in `load'
/usr/local/bin/cucumber:22:in `<main>'
```

Here is my

```
RubyGems Environment:
  - RUBYGEMS VERSION: 2.6.11
  - RUBY VERSION: 2.0.0 (2015-12-16 patchlevel 648) [universal.x86_64 darwin16]
  - INSTALLATION DIRECTORY: /Library/Ruby/Gems/2.0.0
  - USER INSTALLATION DIRECTORY: /Users/eun081/.gem/ruby/2.0.0
  - RUBY EXECUTABLE: /System/Library/Frameworks/Ruby.framework/Versions/2.0/usr/bin/ruby
  - EXECUTABLE DIRECTORY: /usr/bin
  - SPEC CACHE DIRECTORY: /Users/eun081/.gem/specs
  - SYSTEM CONFIGURATION DIRECTORY: /Library/Ruby/Site
  - RUBYGEMS PLATFORMS:
    - ruby
    - universal-darwin-16
  - GEM PATHS:
     - /Library/Ruby/Gems/2.0.0
     - /Users/eun081/.gem/ruby/2.0.0
     - /System/Library/Frameworks/Ruby.framework/Versions/2.0/usr/lib/ruby/gems/2.0.0
  - GEM CONFIGURATION:
     - :update_sources => true
     - :verbose => true
     - :backtrace => false
     - :bulk_threshold => 1000
     - "gem" => "--no-document"
  - REMOTE SOURCES:
     - https://rubygems.org/
  - SHELL PATH:
     - /Users/eun081/.rvm/bin
     - /usr/local/bin
     - /usr/bin
     - /bin
     - /usr/sbin
     - /sbin
     - /Users/eun081/.rvm/bin
```

Here is my env.rb:-

```
 require 'rspec'
    require 'watir-webdriver'
    require 'cucumber'
    require 'rake'
    require 'spreadsheet'
    require 'yaml'
    require 'page-object'
    require 'yaml'
```

Here is my gem file:-

```
source "http://rubygems.org"
    gem of "rake"
    gem "cucumber"
    gem "rspec"
    #gem "watir-webdriver"
    gem 'selenium-webdriver','~>2.53.0'
    gem 'watir-webdriver','~>0.9.1'
    gem 'spreadsheet'
    gem 'rubyXL'
    gem 'roo'
    gem 'page-object'
    gem 'require_all'
    gem 'faker'
    gem 'parallel_tests', '~> 2.2', '>= 2.2.2'
    gem 'nokogiri', '1.3.3'
```

Comment: Is `rspec` installed?

Comment: Yes Installed .

Comment: Can you please edit your question and include `env.rb`?

Comment: I added env.rb and gem file also, If you need anything please let me know.

Comment: Run the command `gem list` and verify rspec is listed.  If not, and if bundler is installed then run `bundle install`

Comment: here are gems I installed,  rspec-core (3.5.4)
rspec-expectations (3.5.0)
rspec-mocks (3.5.0)
rspec-support, even bundler also installed builder (3.2.2)
bundle (0.0.1)
bundler (1.14.6)

Comment: You don't have any solutions to this issue.

Comment: This is NOT a problem related to Selenium, or Webdriver, or Watir... Removed the tags for those.   This is a basic issue of a gem not being found where ruby is looking for it when the program is executed.  Either the gem is not properly installed, or Some other issue in that regard.  Removed the other tags as they have nothing to do with the failing code and why it is failing

Answer (score 1):

The answer was in the very first comment 'is rspec installed?' From the list of gems you give in your comments it looks a lot like you have some parts of rspec installed, but not the base rspec gem itself.

You need to run the command `gem install rspec`  (or if you are in the directory with the gem file you listed, you should be able to just run Bundle Install, but it does need to be from that directory, for bundler to find the gemfile)

Clearly you believe you have rspec installed as you have maintained that when asked about it, but the error indicates otherwise.  If you need more proof that this is the issue, see below.

On a clean system just now without rspec installed, my original `gem list` output showed no gems with rspec in the name..

I then ran `gem install rspec`, and after that was done when I ran `gem list rspec` I got the following

```
C:\Users\chuckv>gem list rspec

*** LOCAL GEMS ***

rspec (3.6.0)
rspec-core (3.6.0)
rspec-expectations (3.6.0)
rspec-mocks (3.6.0)
rspec-support (3.6.0)
```

I can then start an IRB session and do `require 'rspec'` and it works  like thus..

```
C:\Users\chuckv>irb
irb(main):001:0> require 'rspec'
=> true
```

If I run `gem uninstall rspec` then it removes JUST the base rspec gem, leaving the others, creating a `gem list` output that looks similar to what you put in the comments.  If I start an IRB session and do `require 'rspec'` then I get basically the same error you did (sans the cucumber call stack)

```
C:\Users\chuckv>gem list rspec

*** LOCAL GEMS ***

rspec-core (3.6.0)
rspec-expectations (3.6.0)
rspec-mocks (3.6.0)
rspec-support (3.6.0)

C:\Users\chuckv>irb
irb(main):001:0> require 'rspec'
LoadError: cannot load such file -- rspec
        from C:/Ruby22/lib/ruby/2.2.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:54:in `require'
        from C:/Ruby22/lib/ruby/2.2.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:54:in `require'
        from (irb):1
        from C:/Ruby22/bin/irb:11:in `<main>'
```

If I then run `gem install rspec` I am back to having `rspec` in the output of `gem list rspec` and the require command works once again.